# Hide & retrieve back present view controller same as Viber

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I am working on the app with Audio/Video calling feature. I want to integrate the feature like minimize video/audio call while video/audio call is ongoing. User can navigate to other view controllers but still, he can retrieve back Audion/Video controller same as Viber does.

Currently, I present the Audio/Video view controller so I have only dismissed option that causes an ongoing call to end. Please help me to know how Viber does this.

I am using callkit to handle A/V incoming call. I have designed CallViewController class who is responsible for layout of A/V call. Below is the way i am presenting CallViewController from Appdelegate.m file.

//I am using Quickblox for Audio/Video call

[CallKitManager.instance reportIncomingCallWithUserIDs:[opponentIDs copy] session:session uuid:self.callUUID onAcceptAction:^{

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Second" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *strongSelf = [Util fetchLastViewcontroller];
        CallViewController *callViewController =
        [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"];

        callViewController.session = session;
        //callViewController.usersDatasource = strongSelf.dataSource;
        callViewController.callUUID = self.callUUID;
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:callViewController];
        self.nav = nav;
        [strongSelf presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:nil];

    } completion:nil]
```

So now if user has to naviagate other screen say chat screen then i needed to dismiss callViewController. But I want that CallViewController still should be in memory & i need to retrieve it back as Viber does.

I have attached the screenshot of Viber

In below image link, user can naviagte to chat screen from A/V call & viceversa
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kodFz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What you’re describing is called CallKit. It is a kit built into iOS by Apple.

Without knowing the specifics of your source code I am unable to help you with integration however this would be a very good reference to get you started

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1276414-callkit-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: @Brandson, Thanks for your response. I have edited the comment. Please advise.

Comment: You have literally changed the entire scope of the question. Your original question was answered and you're now asking for more. It sounds to me as though you are unfamiliar with the basic principles of iOS development and should engage the services of a local professional.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended with adding code to push from CallViewController(resposible for handling audio/video call) to Chat(responsible for chat conversations)class & adding back button on Chat class that will pop to CallViewController. This was not 100% solution for my problem but still, it worked for now.